# Unable to store session in DB

Tags: session, magento, magento-1.9

Morning my website was down ! i get to know that because of file count in my server

Later i noticed the var/session folder have lot of files , i have deleted those session files then my website works fine !

and i was searching for the solution , so someone said instead of keeping session in folder store in database ! [reference link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124101/is-possible-to-delete-folder-var-session-in-magento)

So based on that reference i have made changes in 'app/etc/local.xml'

```
     <session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
```

But still the session files are storing in var/session folder

[image: sessions]

can anyone please let me know where i am wrong ! or anything else i can do to solve this ?

Comment: Have you changed i the app/etc/local.xml: <session_save>db</session_save>? Please let me know the version of the magento

Comment: @Jinesh . So based on that reference i have made changes in 'app/etc/local.xml'

     <session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>

Comment: Run this command rm var/session -rf then check this folder

Comment: @Jinesh i have manually deleted those files , then i changed to <session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>  !  after the changes also the files are storing !

Comment: Can you check core_session table in database?

Comment: @Jinesh Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Comment: @Jinesh core_session table is empty !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195056/discussion-between-jinesh-and-manikanta-gowda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this do the following step

Open app/etc/local.xml:

Change

```
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
```

To

```
<session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
```

Then clear the content of the var folder and check the session folder.